Make SEDE queries automatically run after the captcha is completed
On the SE Data Explorer, anonymous visitors must complete a captcha. This isn’t unreasonable at all.
The captcha presents after “Run Query” is clicked/pressed. After the captcha is completed, visitors must click “Run Query” again, to run the query.
A wise wizard user once told me that great buildings are built from very small bricks.
This feature request doesn’t seem like a big deal, but to be completely honest, it’s annoying, and possibly unnecessary.
Is it possible for the query to run automatically after the captcha is completed?
Is there a technological (or other) reason why this couldn’t work?
If it is possible, is there a reason why this isn’t the case already?
